# generic problem

Tags: java, generics

HI:
What is the generic type in java? Just for reduce the class cast exception?

ALso, the K means "keys", V means "valuse", what about the E and T?

For a generic class,for example:
List, I understand it as that the list can only put object of String type,but I am not quite clear about the generic method:

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o); // Correct
    }
}
```

WHat does the T means in the above>? Can anyone give me a plain expaination?

I read the tutorial by sun,however I can not understand yet. So I wish someone can explain it without too much Professional words.

Comment: Calling it T is (just) a convention. You could call it Item (or FuzzyBear) if you wanted. Anyway, it's a placeholder for a "generic type" in that context (appears inside the <>'s).

Comment: I know, it's only an example but there are `Arrays.asList(T...)` and `Collections.addAll(Collection, T...)` for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter E and T stand for Element and Type respectively, but take note they are not enforced by the compiler or anything like that. You can pretty much put anything there including full words, but it's recommended you use single capital letters so it's better to distinguish them (lowercase words look like variable names, words starting with capital letters look like classes, and full uppercase words look like constants)

As for the use, think of it this way. When you create an array you can create `Object[]`, `String[]`, `Integer[]`, `SomeClass[]`, which tells you exactly what is in there. Until generics where introduced the collections/map classes (List, Set, Map) had the problem that you could put anything in there (some may argue that that's not a problem). So now you can create `List<String>`, `List<Object>` similar to arrays. There are some differences though. For example `String[]` extends `Object[]`, but `List<String>` does NOT extend `List<Object>` so you can't put a string list instance in a object list variable.

The advantage of generics is that you can have them on any class, and a class can have more than one generic parameter (like `Map<K, V>`). You can think of it as `Class` parameters given to instances of other classes, that tell them what types their methods should receive or return.

And yes the point is that the compiler can check if you give them the right kind of parameters, so that you can avoid ClassCastExceptions which would appear at runtime. For example before generics you could do:

```
String s = "";
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add(s);
Integer i = (Integer)l.get(0); // ClassCastException
```

but with generics:

```
String s = "";
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add(s);
Integer i = (Integer)l.get(0); // compiler warning: cannot cast from String to Integer
```

Also, you can have a generic type parameter on a single method like in your example (the class itself doesn't need to have a type parameter for this). This tells the compiler that that method must match all instances of the type parameter on the method parameters and/or return type. In your example calling it like:

```
String[] a = new String[1];
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
fromArrayToCollection(a, l);
```

will result in a compile error, since the method must receive a `T[]` and a `Collection<T>`, T here being the same. But you gave it a `String[]` (so T here is String) and a `List<Integer>` (so T here is Integer, not String). If l was `List<String>` though, it would work.
Also notice that `List<T>` extends `Collection<T>` since List extends Collection, but `List<T>` does not extends `List<S>` even if T extends S (whatever T and S may be).

Oh, and you can have wildcards on generics specifying limits for the classes that may replace the type paramter:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, COllection<T> c);
```

This way the method will work if you give it SomeClass[] or SomeChildClass[] (where SomeChildClass that extends SomeClass), but not Object[] or String[].

Answer (score 1):

T stands for Type. When you instantiate a generic class, you must specify the type contained in the instance. Thus, instead of having a collection of Objects, you can have a collection of String or MyType or WhateverType.

Generics give a class compile-time type safety. If you try to stick the wrong data-type into a generic collection, you will get a compiler warning. Personally, I prefer that by a mile over catching a cast exception. Also, there is no need to cast from type Object when retrieving from a Generic collection, unlike non-Generic collections.

Comment: Thanks.<br>"static <T> void" what does this "T" act? this method return type is void, so I wonder the usage of the T here.

Answer (score 0):

The  in

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c)
```

declares "T" being a generic type instead the name of a certain class. Otherwise, the compiler would look for a class with the name "T".